# Firebase Android and GTM: app install and update events?

Tags: android, ios, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I am running Firebase on both iOS and Android version of my app. I also run GTM to get events and screen views for GA property and reporting.

In the iOS GTM container, I have First Open and App Update events(triggers) built in, however in Android GTM container, there are no First Open and App Update triggers.

I have tried to to custom event trigger with event name as "first_open" or "_f". Neither worked.

How can this be achieved in Android GTM containers?